# How to create automatic partitions on a non-time based column in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, hashing

I want to create a partition on a column which is of type `serial`. A hash based partition seems appropriate here. But from what I understand I will need to create all the partitions myself (based on remainder). Is there a way to create all the partitions (say 10 partitions) using some automated extension like pg-partman?

Comment: Hash partitioning uses a fixed number of partitions (and is pretty useless), so that's just a one-time effort. `pg_partman` will create partitions based on time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built into Postgres to do "automatic partition creation", so you either need to write a little script that automates that process or use a tool like pg_partman if it supports that.

In `psql` you could use a query like this to generate the `create table` statements and then run it using `\g`:

```
select format('create table %I partition of my_table for values with (modulus 10, remainder %s);', 'my_table_p'||to_char(g.i, 'FM00'), g.i)
from generate_series(0,9) as g(i)
\g
```

Otherwise just use a `do` block:

```
do
$$
declare
  l_sql text;
begin  
  for i in 0..9 loop
    l_sql := format('create table %I partition of my_table for values with (modulus 10, remainder %s)', 'my_table_p'||to_char(i, 'FM00'), i);
    execute l_sql;
  end loop;
end;
$$
;
```

**Not tested!**

Of course you can put the PL/pgSQL loop into a function or procedure and call it with the number of partitions you want.